# 60's or 70's book where kids find interdimensional portal

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel

It was a kid or young adult book.  A bunch of kids find a disk or coin-like object that can be activated into a room or fort.  I think they could travel to another dimension or planet though this fort.  I don't remember too much clearly, but I do remember a toddler eating some weeds identified by another kid as a Jimson weed (which is poisonous) thus saving the toddler from serious illness.